# htaccess redirect domain.com to www.domain.com except of staging.domain.com for multiple domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following htaccess do redirect people who not have the "www" or "staging" subdomain in the url to the www.domain.com subdomain

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.domain.com|staging.domain.com)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now I'd like to have the same generic for multiple domains. However the following isn't working:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www|staging|dev).(^\.*).(de|lo))$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.$2.de/$4 [L,R=301]
```

Returns in an configuration error.

Thx I appreciate your help!

Comment: may you mean to say what is explained here 
[htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306226/how-can-i-stop-my-htaccess-redirecting-my-sub-domain-to-main-site/19659822#19659822)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|staging|dev)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+\.)?([^\.]+)\.(de|lo)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.%2.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`%2` will match `([^\.]+)` from the RewriteCond, which will match any character that isn't a `.` between `!(www|staging|dev).` and `.(de|lo)`

Comment: thx @arco444 working fine. Is $1 always set automatically? For normal regex this is the first round brackets or?

Comment: Is replacing domain with blank resulting in an redirect to www..de

Comment: `$1` comes from the `(.*)` in the RewriteRule, in this case it means the whole request (i.e. everything but domain name). `$` groups always come from the RewriteRule, `%` groups always come from the RewriteCond

Comment: Updated to avoid your blank domain situation

Comment: why did you split it up in 2 lines?

Comment: Couldn't make it work in one! Something to do with the fact you're doing a not match on www|staging|dev was playing havoc with retrieving the values from the group so had to move that bit out. It's not _two lines_, it's two conditions in a logical AND. More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)